# How to change focus with two textboxes?

Tags: jquery, jsp, textbox, focus

I have two textboxes

```
   <input id="input1" type="text"/>
   <input id="input2" type="text"/>
```

Here is the script that I'm currently using:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#input1").focus();
     $("#input1").onclick(function(){
      changeFocus('input1');
      return false;
 });

     $("#input2").onclick(function(){
      changeFocus("input2");
      return false;
 });
});

     function changeFocus(id){
       var v = "#" + id;
       $(v).focus();
}
</script>
```

The problem is that when I click the 2nd textbox and the page refreshes the focus will return to the 1st textbox. Could somebody help me so that when I click the 2nd textbox the focus will remain even the page refreshes?

Comment: you'd need to use local storage and/or the url location hash and/or a cookie to store the ID of the focused element. when a page is reloaded the JS engine is totally restarted and all vars are lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
changeFocus();
 $("#input1").click(function(){
  localStorage.setItem('txtObjectid', "input1");
  changeFocus();
  return false;
 });

 $("#input2").click(function(){
  localStorage.setItem('txtObjectid', "input2");
  changeFocus();
  return false;
 });
});

 function changeFocus(){
   if(localStorage.getItem('txtObjectid')==null)
       id="input1"
   else
       id=localStorage.getItem('txtObjectid');
   var v = "#" + id;
   $(v).focus();
}
</script>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9R6Mn/)**